# Timer(unknown resolve error) xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

To avoid initiating a search on every keypress in the search view, i want to add a countdown timer that is restarted on every change to the filter text to delay the search so we only search after the user stops typing. so that i tried to declare Timer in Core but it blinks in red colour and shows unknown resolve error but the Timer works in UI.Droid. I noticed that the system.dll is present in UI.Droid and UI.Touch but in Core it was located in References/.net portable subset. i tried to add the system.dll from .net assembly but i cannot able to find. hope u understand my problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the Core DLL from your Mono install and reference it in your PCL project. You'll want to add the .dll to the following directory on your Mac workstation: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/VERSION_NUMBER_HERE/lib/mono/.NET VERSION HERE/ mscorlib.dll
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/VERSION_NUMBER_HERE/lib/mono/.NET VERSION HERE/ system.dll

However, you cannot move them out of the /.net portable subset folder on neither Mac nor Windows workstations because they are dependent on the .NET profile. 
(thanks for the help Allie)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use Timer in the PortableLibrary, only in Droid or Touch project

Comment: So what's the alternative?